# How to have multiple Enviromental variables (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: linux, macos, flutter

I have installed Python3 for MacOS (Catalina) with the setup that they provide. Python works perfectly on the console, and now I'm trying to install Flutter as another environmental variable.

I tried:

- Creating a file `nano $HOME/ .zshrc`,
- Putting this inside that file 
  `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/bryanenid/Documents/Coding/configs/flutter/bin"`
- Re-open the console and nothing!

When I do `echo $PATH`, I see that python is using that variable.
Is there a way to have multiple variables like `$PATH_FLUTTER` permanently and making the terminal recognize all of them?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

- Open up Terminal.
- Run the following command: `sudo nano /etc/paths`
- Enter your password, when prompted.
- Go to the bottom of the file, and enter the path you wish to add. In this case: `/Users/bryanenid/Documents/Coding/configs/flutter/bin`
- Hit control-x to quit.
- Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.
- Enter again
- That’s it!  To test it, in new terminal window, type the tool you want to use, in my case `flutter`

Reference: [Link](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg)

Comment: This changes a system-wide configuration to point to one user's home. You may get away with this if you're the only user on that machine. I'd generally not do that; it can break easily, and you should not need root privileges for modifying your user settings. I'd rather figure out why your `.zshrc` is not executed.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will try to figure that out then. Thanks for the comment